# Please simplify this sigma question?

Tags: summation

I am not able to solve this sigma question. Please anybody solve this question by steps.
$$\sum_{R=1}^N\left(\frac13\right)^{R-1}$$

Comment: That's a geometric progression. Bad luck at Wimbledon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r=\frac13$, and 
$$S_N=\sum_{R=1}^N\left(\frac13\right)^{R-1}=\sum_{R=1}^Nr^{R-1}$$

You have
$$rS_N=r\sum_{R=1}^Nr^{R-1}=\sum_{R=1}^Nr^R$$
Then
$$S(r-1)=rS-S=\sum_{R=1}^Nr^R-\sum_{R=1}^Nr^{R-1}=\cdots=r^N-r^0$$
So
$$S=\dfrac{1-r^N}{1-r}=\frac32\left(1-\frac1{3^N}\right)$$